# Files and folders under mnt/sdcard/ File Explorer in Eclipse

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I got a Samsung Tablet GT-N8000. When I choose the device in DDMS, and check the sdcard folder under `File Explorer` in eclipse, I have not access to any file or folder.

[image]

As you can see in the image, the sdcard folder is not expandable. I have restart the device couple of times and still have the same problem.

I have worked with some other samsung and HTC devices, but never I had this problem. I need to pull out a database file from sdcard.

Could you help me what the problem is?

Addenda : I am able to access the file using My Files app on the device or Astro File Manager. But not File Explorer in Eclipse.

Comment: you need to root your tablet i guess.

Comment: @Raghunandan I guess he don't need to root the device as DDMS has access to the external storage

Comment: try neighbour folders inside mnt. Not all devices have sdcrad mounted to /mnt/sdcard

Comment: yes @user527759 is right you should try other folders also

Comment: yup to access sdcard i don't think you need to root.

Comment: @user527759 you are right. I was somehow careless. You can share your answer in order to accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try neighbouring folders inside mnt. Not all devices have the SD card mounted to /mnt/sdcard

Comment: Thanks! My SD card was /mnt/shell/emulated/0/  And I was looking for my app data folder /mnt/shell/emulated/0/Android/data/